# How to style a subset of some text in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```
<h2><div class='q'>Q:</div> Does alfredo sauce contain soy?</h2>
```

and then styling it in my CSS file, like so:

```
.q {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #65A6D1;
}
```

While this displays fine in my browser, when running the page through http://validator.w3.org, it complains: "Element div not allowed as child of element h2 in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)"

How would I style this piece of text in valid HTML/CSS?

Comment: Sounds like you need to [read the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/spec.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a span

```
<h2><span class='q'>Q:</span> Does alfredo sauce contain soy?</h2>
```

also remove display: inline from the class

```
.q {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    /*display: inline;*/
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #65A6D1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a span instead of a div inside the h2.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<span>` tag instead of `<div>`. `<span>` is an inline element, while `<div>` is a block element.

Answer (score 1):

A div creates a new block element. These are forbidden in h2 and many other elements. You can create an inline element with span.

```
<h2><span class='q'>Q:</span> Does alfredo sauce contain soy?</h2>
```

Of course, you need to change the stylesheet accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`div` and `h2` are both block elements.  Use `span` instead of `div`.

For example:

```
<h2><span class="q">Q:</span> Blammy blammo soy?</h2>
```

additional note: [Non-normative description] Some elements don't like to contain block elements.  The header (h1, h2, ...) elements don't like to contain block elements.  "Don't like": the spec says "should not" I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<h2 id="q"><span>Q</span>Does alfredo sauce contain soy?</h2>

h2#q span {
padding-bottom: 15px;
display: inline;
font-size: 35px;
font-weight: 700;
color: #65A6D1;

}
```